# UBUNTU - планировщик задач CRON, политики безопасности IPTABLES

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Всем привет.
Такой вопрос - в cron добавить правило запрета входящих соединений по ssh c 20:00 ​​по 10:00 следующего дня.
Просьба расписать все команды, вводимые в терминал. (ssh сервер установлен).
Заранее спасибо

Comment: А если сервер случайно сломается в 20:01, то потом его целых четырнадцать часов никто не сможет починить?

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит `cron` этим тревожить — `iptables` сам умеет применять правила по времени. Подразумевая, что у цепочки `INPUT` стоит политика по умолчанию `DROP`, разрешить соединения с 10:00 до 20:00 можно таким правилом:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m time --timestart 10:00 --timestop 20:00 -j ACCEPT
```

см. [документацию](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCH) модуля `time` в `man iptables-extensions`.

ЗЫ: На практике делать это — не очень хорошая идея: При возникновении экстренных неисправностей в неурочные часы доступ по ssh может оказаться очень полезным.

Comment: А если добавить впереди правило, разрешающее коннект всегда с определенного ip (или диапазона)?

Comment: @de_frag, добавь, я не против...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но суть - именно реализовать задачу через crontab